# Prevent Origami (folding@home) from using all cores

Tags: fan

After installing Origami, my CPU fan starts running full-speed constantly. This I'd like to prevent because it is too much of a distraction when not using the system.

I've noticed all cores are utilized by default. I.e. 6 folding@home instances are running at 100%.
I would expect fan speed going down when I switch to e.g. using only 2 cores but I can't find how to do this. The author of Origami did not respond to the issue so far. Using something like cpulimit is something I'd like to prevent.

Does anyone know how to achieve using less cores?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FoldingAtHome

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [ubuntu faq about Origami](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FoldingAtHome/origami) the only solution to limit cpu usage is cpulimit... BUT, according to the page for [F@H on Notebook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FoldingAtHome#Folding%20on%20a%20Notebook), you can configure your cpu governor to ignore nice processes, so the frequency will not grow up when starting Origami :

`echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load`

or in your /etc/rc.local to activate it at boot :

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load
# ... and the same for each cpuN
```

You can change your cpu governor by using [cpufreq-set](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpufreq-set) :

```
cpufreq-set -r -g ondemand  # will set the governor ondemand

cpufreq-set -r -g performance  # will set the governor performance
```

Here is the list of the cpu governors :

- **ondemand** scales up CPU speed as long as the CPU load remains high.
- **conservative** does the same, but slower, and backs off quicker
- **performance** stays at the max CPU speed, all the time.
- **powersave** stays at the min CPU speed, all the time.